# Writing Firebase database rules when user information are on another server

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need to implement chatting for a mobile app that talks to my own server, so the registered user information is on my own server. So, if I use firebase real-time database for chatting, how do I write the security rules like these:

```
".read": "auth != null", ".write": "auth != null"
```

So the scenario is, my user's information are on my own server, in my own database. I want to use firebase to implement a chat

How do I write the database rules that prevents anyone from reading the messages from database (by hitting the URL maybe ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is precisely the scenario that [Firebase Custom Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server) was made for.

On your server you authenticate your user against your own user database, then you mint a JSON Web Token with the information about that user that you want Firebase to know. At the very least the token should contain a `uid`, but it may contain more information that you can then access in your security rules. Once you've created the JWT, return it to your user.

In your app, you then use the JWT to sign in with Firebase. For example on Android that means, you'll [call the `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#next-steps).

For more information see the [Firebase Database Server documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server).